# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: doesn't work

Tags: ios, nsstring

I want my output to be "23", but it still shows "123".

```
NSString *valorTextField = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"123"];
    [valorTextField stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@", valorTextField);
```

Comment: Try it this way: `NSString *valorTextField; valorTextField = @"123";
    [valorTextField stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@", valorTextField);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` returns a *new* string:

```
NSString *valorTextField = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"123"];
NSString *replaced = [valorTextField stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", replaced);
```

Alternatively, you can work with a `NSMutableString` and use the 
`replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` method.

Answer (score 4):

You are not assigning returned string to `valorTextField` again. You are just executing function. Actual string is unchanged. Instead write:

```
valorTextField  = [valorTextField stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", valorTextField);
```

Comment: Of course you can assign a new value to `valorTextField`. *Immutable* means that you cannot modify the string object that `valorTextField` points to.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood that thing.. Thanks for pointing that out :)